# Linking SDL library in CLion on Windows 10

Tags: c, cmake, sdl, clion

I am currently having trouble when i am trying to link the "SDL" library to clion. I am running a windows 10 computer. Here is my CmakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(testing2)

#includes cmake/FindSDL2.cmake
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})

set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.c)

add_executable(testing2 ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(testing2 ${SDL2_LIBRARY})
```

I am using these "FindSDL2.cmake": https://github.com/tcbrindle/sdl2-cmake-scripts.

When i reload the CMakeLists.txt it says that the SDL2 cannot be found. I have made a directory on my desktop where I have stored the SDL files.

Comment: Why not the included FindSDL.cmake? Does it not support SDL2? https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/module/FindSDL.html

Answer (score 0):

This is for anyone with a similar problem.

I managed to fix this by basically deleting everything I had tried.

I downloaded the MinGW compiler, and chose these packages:

- mingw-developer-toolkit
- mingw32-base
- mingw32-gcc-g++
- msys-base

After that I downloaded the "OpenGL-tutorial_v0015_33" from [opengl-tutorial.org](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/download/). And that worked (I really don't know what to do if that doesn't work). And afterwards simply salvaged the small parts of the code I needed, if you know a little bit about CMake files you'll figure out what you'll need, and it is slightly commented.

Good luck to anyone else wanting to traverse this treacherous path.